# How is energy stored in the cotransport of molecules down to its electrochemical gradient?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, energy

I am talking about symporters and antiporters, that transport usually an amino acid against its concentration gradient while at the same time transport another molecule down its electrochemical or concentration gradient or both. It is said that "cotransporters use the energy stored in electrochemical gradient", but I do not understand what do they refer to when talking about storing energy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Laura not sure what exactly your question means. Please read the theory about electrochemical **potentials** in general and ask your question again.

Comment: Please give a source for your quotation, with a link if possible.  For one thing, it lacks context, and for another the lack of an article before “electrochemical” suggests you are paraphrasing or quoting from memory. We need more and precise information if we are to help you.